# Unable to fetch the html source after successfully logging in

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I want to fetch the html source of a few pages of a website. Using `request.Sessions`, I am able to successfully login there (200 response). But after that, when I try to fetch html source of certain pages, I am getting html source of login page again. This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
from time import sleep

USERNAME = "email"
PASSWORD = "password"

LOGIN_URL = "login_url"
URL = "base_url"
FILEPATH = "File_Location"

with requests.Session() as s:

    r = s.get(LOGIN_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    hidden = soup.find_all("input", {'type':'hidden'})
    target = LOGIN_URL + soup.find("form")['action']
    payload = {x["name"]: x["value"] for x in hidden}

    #add login creds to the dict
    payload["user[email]"] = USERNAME
    payload["user[password]"] = PASSWORD
    r = s.post(target, data=payload)
    print(r) \\-> <Response [200]>

    for i in range(587, 608):
        sleep(randint(1,5))
        url1 = URL + str(i)
        result = s.get(url1, headers = dict(referer = url1))
        fn = FILEPATH + str(i) + ".html"
        data = result.text   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser") // -> This gives me login page's source code
```

Comment: see you need to set something in the session after login . There is no bearer token,no cookie or any header set in the request.session after login that makes the server know that you have indeed logged in.

Comment: first use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to see all requests which browser sends to server - and see if it send extrad data (ie. cookies and headers) after loging. And later you have create similar requests in your code.

Comment: `200` doesn't mean you logged correctly but it means only server correctly send HTML. You have to check if HTML has some element which exists only after loging. You could also save HTML and open it editor or browser to see if there is no extra information about wrong login or password. Or maybe login form has hidden `<input>` and you have to send it with login and password - it is popular method to block bots/script. OR maybe page displays recaptcha and you have to send correct value.